# Generate AC COMMAND is not working on AMEX card

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv

I have CDOL1 and i have successfully generate AC command and it works on Visa card and i get Success code but it is not working on AMEX card although AMEX have same CDOL1 command.

**CDOL1**

```
9F02 06 - Authorised amount of the transaction (excluding adjustments)
9F03 06 - Secondary amount associated with the transaction representing a cashback amount
9F1A 02 - the country of the terminal
95   05 - Status of the different functions as seen from the terminal
5F2A 02 - the currency code of the transaction
9A   03 - Local date that the transaction was authorised 
9C   01 - the type of financial transaction
9F37 04 - Value to provide variability and uniqueness to the generation of a cryptogram
```

**Generate AC Command**

```
80 AE 5000 1D 000000001000 000000000000 0040 0000000000 0978 150528 00 661D7D59 00
```

Comment: In order to answer what could go wrong here we would certainly need more information (e.g. show us what commands you sent before the GENERATE AC and what responses you got).

Answer (score 0):

From AEIPS 4.1 Card specification: "Combined Dynamic Data Authentication/Application Cryptogram Generation is not supported by this version of AEIPS." Later CDA is optional to support at EMV terminals.

Last Le byte 0x00 might be excluded from command. Could be a case.

In the sample GenAC1 APDU command P1 = 0x50, meant:

```
- P1: "50" # Parameter 1
    # [01______] bits 8 to 7, Transaction Certificate (TC), Transaction approved
    # [___1____] bit 5, requested CDA signature
```

I guess TC + CDA is not good case to generate first AC at Amex AEIPS cards.

If you really want to get TC from your card try to request TC only, P1 = 0x40.